# Iteration of an Unknown Number in C#

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a formula which contains a variable that user has to guess. But at the end of formula, that variable is calculated again and if the first one and second one doesn't match, formulation has to be solved again with a new value. Shortly assume that I have a formula like this (mine is much more complex and longer than this);

```
        double y1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtboxPredefinedY.Text);
        double x, z, Ort;
        double y2 = 0;

        while (y1 != y2)
        {
            x = (Math.Pow(y1, 2)) + 10;
            z = (y1 - 2) / 3;
            y2 = (x / z);

            Ort = (y2 + y1)/2;
            y1 = Ort;

            if (y1 == y2)
                break;
        }

        txtboxResult.Text = r.ToString();
```

So the `y1` variable I defined first has to match the last variable `y2`. To achieve this I calculate the whole formula and find a new `y1`, re-calculate formula.

I want to define a `y1` value and let the application correct me. For example this code should return me a value of `3.3158`. If first input is `3.3158` than `y1` becomes equal to `y2`.

I couldn't use `while` iteration correctly. How can I fix this? Or maybe, how should I build my `while` block to give me exact equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with `Double` you should compare with ***tolerance***:

```
  double y1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtboxPredefinedY.Text);
  double x, z, Ort;
  double y2 = 0;

  double tolerance = 0.001;

  while (Math.Abs(y1 - y2) >= tolerance)  {
    x = (Math.Pow(y1, 2)) + 10;
    z = (y1 - 2) / 3;
    y2 = (x / z);

    Ort = (y2 + y1)/2;
    y1 = Ort;
  }
```

Comparisons like `y1 != y2` as well as `y1 == y2` may fail because of *round-up errors*.

Comment: Dear Dmitry thank you very much. When I set the while iteration to consider tolerance as you said; it found nearly the exact match. I just had to decrease tolerance. Thank you very much.